# How to pop up a confirmation dialog after user clicks the "Close Order" button of SO in NetSuite?

Tags: javascript, dom, netsuite, suitescript2.0

There is a **Close Order** button in the Sales Order.

[image: The "Close Order" button]

If user clicks the button, the Sales Order will be closed.

We want to pop up a dialog to confirm the click, if user clicks "**Yes**", then the Sales Order will close; if user clicks "**No**", it will return to the page and nothing happens.

I know the button id for the Close Order is "**closeremaining**", and we can use the following code to show to confirmation dialog:

```
    var options = {
        title: "Are you sure you want to close the order?",
        message: "Press OK or Cancel"
    };

    function success(result) {
        console.log("Success with value " + result);
    }

    function failure(reason) {
        console.log("Failure: " + reason);
    }
    dialog.confirm(options).then(success).catch(failure);
```

But we don't know how to pop the dialog after user clicks the button in **VIEW** mode. I tried the following but in vain:

```
 var closeOrderBtn = document.getElementById("closeremaining");
 closeOrderBtn.addEventListener("click", showConfirmDialog);
```

Can anyone give me help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, triggering a script from a Standard Button(Close Order) is not yet possible. What you can do is to hide the standard button and replace it with a custom one so you can have full control of its functionality.

Here is an overview of what you need to do:

1. Hide the Close Order button
2. Deploy a User Event script and add a button through it
3. Use a client script to add the functionality that will be performed by the script (Show confirm pop-up)
4. You can then proceed to close the order by changing the isclosed field to 
   True in the item sublists

Also, you can read SuiteAnswers article: SuiteScript > Confirm before Closing a Transaction Record (Id: 65115) since it has a step by step guide on how to implement it. You can use the Id when searching.

Comment: How about using a suitelet to handle the logic of updating the isclosed filed?

Comment: @skyclouder yup! You can use a Suitelet to update the Sales Order. Just the pass the Internal Id to the Suitelet to load and modify it there.